# Nuget package not installing, failed to add reference

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I'm running a local NuGetServer v2.11.3.0 and I'm trying to install custom packages that I have created. I ran into an issue when I try to install the package and I get the following error.

```
Failed to add reference to 'mycustomdll'.
```

I don't understand why the file I'm trying to install is having an issue referencing itself.

When I created the spec file for this package, I name the ID, the same as the dll name. This wasn't working so I tried to change the Id to another value and then the package installed.

Is there some rule where the package name can't be the name as the dll name?

Comment: You find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#choosing-a-unique-package-identifier-and-setting-the-version-number) the documented rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nuget Folder in my personal Appdata folder had some weird references. I deleted these files and everything started working correctly.